# What is $\frac{z_1+z_2}{z_1−z_2}$ if $z_1,z_2\in\mathbb{C}$, such that $z_1\neq z_2,|z_1|\neq|z_2|$

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers

> Let $z_1$ and $z_2$ be two complex numbers such that $z_1≠z_2$ and $|z_1|\neq|z_2|$. If $z_1$ has positive real part and $z_2$ has negative imaginary part, then $\frac{z_1+z_2}{z_1−z_2}$ may be ___________
>
> a) zero or purely imaginary
>
> b) real and +ve
>
> c) real and -ve

My reference gives the solution "zero or purely imaginary". If it was $|z_1|=|z_2|$ I can easily find the solution from geometry as the complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$ form a rhombus and $z_1+z_2$ and $z_1-z_2$ be its diagonals and they intersect orthoganally, thus $\arg\Big(\frac{z_1+z_2}{z_1-z_2}\Big)=\arg(z_1+z_2)-\arg(z_1-z_2)=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$, thus purely imaginary. But, in this case how do I find the solution ?

Comment: For $z_1 = 2$ and $z_2 = -i$ I get $(z_1+z_2)/(z_1 - z_2) = (3+4 i)/5$, therefore I cannot see how "zero or purely imaginary" can be the correct solution.

Comment: @MartinR My reference gives that solution, i'm confused.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not $z_1\neq z_2$ and $|z_1|=|z_2|$?

Comment: I agree with Reinhard Meier, there is apparently a typo. If $|z_1|\neq|z_2|,\;$ all three possibilities can occur.